# Certificate issue in Kestrel ssl JSON configuration using .net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, ssl-certificate, kestrel-http-server, .net-core-3.1

I have seen this question answered but it doesn't seem to be working for .net core 3.1
This code finds the Certificate:

```
using (var store = new X509Store("Root", StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certCollection = store.Certificates;  
    var currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "*.timedesk.com", false);
    if (currentCerts.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("Https certificate is not found.");
}
```

This appsettings.json does not find the certificate:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Https": {
      "URL": "https://toast.timedesk.com:443",
      "Scheme": "https",
      "Certificate": {
        "Store": "Root",
        "Location": "LocalMachine",
        "Subject": "*.timedesk.com",
        "AllowInvalid": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Gives the follow error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The requested certificate *.timedesk.com could not be found in LocalMachine/Root with AllowInvalid setting: False.'
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue, the Cert on the server did not have a private key.  Once i got a private key this started working.[Cert showing it now has private key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl6PC.png)

Answer (score 0):

My issue is the custom dev certificate was installed into the Personal | Certificates instead of Web Hosting | Certificates store. Easy fix, drag -n- drop.